# how to generate GET and POST methods in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a navbar which has multiple options or in other words some multiple time spans. I want to query my data present on my web page on the basis of these time span options.

[image]

The problem is I don't know how to generate `GET` and `POST` methods for this . If someone can help me out and guide me in this regard. The image is attached above and the marked portion are the options I am talking about.

Comment: `@Url.Action("GetData", new { time = 30 });`? Hard to say exactly without seeing your controller code.

Comment: @itsme86 can you elaborate a bit that how it works?

Comment: what is your progress and where you are stucked? please provide some code..?? Are you trying ajax..??

Comment: @itsme86 here is the link to my controller
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ivzh39n090rx46/HomeController.cs?dl=0

Comment: @itsme86 there is the link
https://www.dropbox.com/work?preview=HomeController.cs

Comment: Do you want ajax request..??

Comment: @SadidKhan no I am not trying ajax here...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are not using ajax here. 
But you can do some simple get request to get the data without Ajax. You can just use anchor tag of Html.

You can do something like this,

```
<a href="/Controller/ActionName?parameterName=userYourParameterHere">Button Name</a>
```

and in Home Controller,

```
public ActionResult GetInvoices(parameterType parameterName)
{
    data = "your query to get data from server"
    return View(data);
}
```

But use an ajax request instead.

Comment: i can't get this line in working.

<a href="/Controller/ActionName?parameterName=@Model.ToString()">Button Name</a>

I am getting @Model exception.

Comment: And kindly guide me how to use ajax here?

Comment: @Awais post all the code you have in your view, because it's really hard to guess what it is and everything you'll find here will be based on assumptions like assuming you have strongly typed view.

Comment: @Awais are you new in asp.net or web developing? If yes then I suggest you to google for some tutorial. It will help you to create a base understanding and then you can ask specific question.

Comment: @Ghukas here is the link to the view file

https://www.dropbox.com/work?preview=About.cshtml